# Не запускается Docker container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, sh

Не запускается Docker когда использую entrypoint.sh Выдает ошибку

> ```
> ERROR: for debt_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: 
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": 
> stat usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
>
> ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: 
> starting container process caused: exec: "usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh": stat 
> usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
> ```

Вот мой dockerfile

```yaml
FROM python:3.8-alpine
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add g++ gcc libxml2 libxslt-dev
COPY ./req.txt .
RUN pip install -r req.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# copy project
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py makemigrations
sleep 20
python manage.py migrate

gunicorn debt.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload -w 4
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'

    services:
      web:
       build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
          - ./:/usr/src/app/
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        env_file:
          - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
          - db
      db:
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=debt_user
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
          - POSTGRES_DB=debt

    volumes:
      postgres_data:
```

Я пробовал добавить `RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh`, но это не помогло((

Так же я пробовал через CMD
`RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh`
`CMD ["usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]`

И docker запускается, но тогда не срабатывают команды внутри
`entrypoint.sh`

Answer (score 1):

В Dockerfile в ENTRYPOINT стоит указать полный путь, а не относительный

То есть написать вот так

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Такой докер файл работает:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add g++ gcc libxml2 libxslt-dev
COPY ./req.txt .
RUN pip install -r req.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
# copy project
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: К сожалени. я так делал и не помогло. У меня ведь в примере так

Comment: Ошибка та же самая?

Comment: Да, таже самая, не найден файл

Comment: Попробуйте запустить без volumes в docker compose

Comment: Ведь если там указать плохой путь, то внутри контейнера в указанной папке все стирается

Comment: Убрал все volumes, не помогло(